# HTML5 Canvas globalCompositeOperation lighter and source-atop at same time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to use the globalCompositeOperation "lighter" and at the same time use source-atop? (Aka lighter but only where there is already something drawn.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set one compositing operation at a time.

**Workaround: You can use a second canvas to do your "lightenAtop":**

1. Create a second in-memory canvas.
2. Draw your main canvas content onto the in-memory canvas.
3. Set compositing to `lighten` on the in-memory canvas
4. Draw your overlaying color/image onto the in-memory canvas
5. Set compositing to 'source-in' on the main canvas.
6. Draw the in-memory canvas onto the main canvas.
7. Result: Combination of lighten & source-atop compositing!

Left: **original red rect**, Middle: **blue fill**, Right: **lightenAtop**

[image][image][image]

Example code and a Demo:

*This example just lightens with a solid fill, but you could alternatively `drawImage` instead of `fillRect`*

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.fillStyle='rgba(250,0,0,255)';
ctx.fillRect(50,50,100,75);

lightenAtop('rgba(0,0,255,255)');

function lightenAtop(rgba){
  var compositor=document.createElement('canvas');
  var cctx=compositor.getContext('2d');
  compositor.width=canvas.width;
  compositor.height=canvas.height;
  cctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
  cctx.globalCompositeOperation='lighter';
  cctx.fillStyle=rgba;
  cctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
  ctx.drawImage(compositor,0,0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Original red rect "lightened" with blue rect</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```